# Error while implementing XSSF example

Tags: excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I want to read large Excel files (.xlsx) with java. Apache has an example how to go this [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api).
So I just copied the whole class, added the path to my .xlsx file and tried to execute it but I get this error:

```
Error:(96, 69) java: cannot access org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTRst
class file for org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTRst not found
```

This error is triggered in this line in the method `endElement()`:

```
lastContents = new XSSFRichTextString(sst.getEntryAt(idx)).toString();
```

I use this dependency for maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI FAQ on this topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from Gagravarr I was able to fix this issue. I just needed to add the following dependencied to maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>stax</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```